# How to use a web.config variable in an HTML header?

Tags: html, web-config, versioning

I have this variable defined in my web.config file :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="version" value="123"/>
</appSettings>
```

and I am using it in my aspx pages' headers without problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css?<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["version"] %>"/>
```

But this doesn't seem to work in a regular HTML page.
What is the correct way of using a web.config variable in straight HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server code (for instance what you have in the `<%%>`) can't be executed on *static* pages.

You need to append this *manually* in your static pages, or convert them to dynamic pages (`.aspx`).

`<%%>` stands for:

```
<script runat="server"></script>
```

In a static page which is not routed through the ASP.NET engine, this will not do anything and will not get converted to server code.

Comment: can you explain how to do that. I have my external resources referenced in Site.Master. It works perfect with .js files: <script src="/resources/js/gtm.min.js?<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CurrentVersion")%>"></script>, but it doesn't work with .css.

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz - How do you mean with `.css`? In an `.aspx` page linking to one? Or **inside** a `.css` file? If the latter - well, `.css` files are static - they do not execute. If so, I suggest looking at LESS/SASS.